# -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution not printing the tenuring age

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

The **-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution** VM option should force the VM to print object ages in the survivor spaces, as noted in the [VMOptions page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

However, when I set this option, I see only the threshold value being printed for each GC, not the tenuring age information.

**Q**: Does anyone know why this option is not working?

The full list of my VM options:

```
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput 
-XX:LogFile=jvm.log -server  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC  
-Xloggc:bin/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -showversion 
-XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC 
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 
-XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:InitialSurvivorRatio=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=3 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 
-Xms8g -Xmx8g -XX:PermSize=512m -Xss256k -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseLargePages 
-XX:+AggressiveOpts -server -XX:-UseBiasedLocking
```

My Java version is :

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I have found this [email thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-use/2012-April/001191.html) mentioning the same issue but it has not been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was added to the Parallel Scavenge collector (-XX:+UseParallelGC)
in jvm 6.0(mustang) build 55.

(From a comment on https://community.oracle.com/thread/1543414?start=0&tstart=0)

I am using "1.6.0_26" and I confirm that I have the same behavior.
To confirm the previous statement, I tried the serial garbage collector (-XX:+UseSerialGC) and tenuring age information is displayed correctly.

```
2014-02-14T16:04:03.285-0500: 686.879: [GC 686.880: [DefNew
Desired survivor size 13402112 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    1288856 bytes,    1288856 total
- age   2:     320312 bytes,    1609168 total
- age   3:       9816 bytes,    1618984 total
- age   4:      33352 bytes,    1652336 total
- age   5:       6256 bytes,    1658592 total
- age   6:      34464 bytes,    1693056 total
- age   7:       9128 bytes,    1702184 total
- age   8:     100192 bytes,    1802376 total
- age   9:       9024 bytes,    1811400 total
- age  10:      55632 bytes,    1867032 total
- age  11:      14616 bytes,    1881648 total
- age  12:     302304 bytes,    2183952 total
- age  13:     682192 bytes,    2866144 total
- age  14:      11928 bytes,    2878072 total
- age  15:      13928 bytes,    2892000 total
```

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it works for `ParallelGC` since JDK6u55. Fair enough.